# How to read number of inputs given in Python

Tags: python, input

The given question is depending upon the number of inputs given (1 input, 2inputs, or 3) finding the circumference of the circle and perimeter's of rectangle and triangle.
I can't seem to figure out how to read the number of inputs give ex: if I give only one input ex:2
the output should be "12.56" and if I give 2 inputs say 2 4 output should be "6"(2*(a+b))
so far I'm done till functions and I'm stuck at inputs

```
def cir(a):
    x=2*3.142*a
    return x
def rec(a,b):
    y=2*(int(a+b))
    return y
def tri(a,b,c):
    z=a+b+c
    return z
a=b=c=0
print("enter the dimenssions")
a,b,c=float(input()),float(input()),float(input())
```

Comment: How are you wanting to separate the inputs? With a space?

Comment: See tutorial on taking multiple inputs in Python [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python-3-6cbe02d03a95).

Comment: @doctorlove yes I want to separate the inputs with space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this should work
(Presuming that you want to separate on a space)

```
def cir(a):
    x=2.0*3.142*float(a)
    return x
def rec(a,b):
    y=2*(float(a)+float(b))
    
    return y
def tri(a,b,c):
    z=float(a)+float(b)+float(c)
    return z

#fun fact, you can put a string inside "input()" and it will have that right before you can type
userInput = input("Enter dimenssions: ")
userInput = userInput.split(" ")#Split the input on all  the spaces

numInputs = len(userInput)#Get how many numbers there are

if(numInputs == 1):
    print("Calculating for cir")
    print(cir(userInput[0]))
elif(numInputs == 2):
    print("Calculating for rect")
    print(rec(userInput[0], userInput[1]))
elif(numInputs == 3):
    print("Calculating for tri")
    print(tri(userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2]))
else:
    print("Error, you entered something wrong :(")
```

Tests:

```
Enter dimenssions: 5
Calculating for cir
31.419999999999998
```

```
Enter dimenssions: 15 7
Calculating for rect
44.0
```

```
Enter dimenssions: 10 2 7
Calculating for tri
19.0
```

I did have to change your perimeter functions for the way I have implemented this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split`:

```
def cir(a):
    return 2 * 3.142 * a
def rec(a, b):
    return 2 * (a + b)
def tri(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

funcs = {1: cir, 2: rec, 3: tri}

try:
    inputs = list(map(float, input("Please give floats space separated ").split()))
except ValueError:
    print("Values must be floats")

try:
    func = funcs[len(inputs)]
    print(f"Using {func.__name__}")
    print(func(*inputs))
except IndexError:
    print("Too many inputs given must be 3 or less")
```

---

```
Please give floats space separated 1
Using cir
6.284

Please give floats space separated 1 2
Using rec
6.0

Please give floats space separated 1 2 3
Using tri
6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are

```
def cir(a):
    x=2*3.142*a
    return x
def rec(a,b):
    y=2*(int(a+b))
    return y
def tri(a,b,c):
    z=a+b+c
    return z

l_input = [float(x) for x in input("Input values:").split()]

print("Input = {}".format(l_input))

if len(l_input) == 1:
    print(cir(*l_input))
elif len(l_input) == 2:
    print(rec(*l_input))
elif len(l_input) == 3:
    print(tri(*l_input))
```

Sample output:

```
Input values:1
Input = [1.0]
6.284


Input values: 1 2
Input = [1.0, 2.0]
6

Input values: 1 2 3 
Input = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe instead "a,b,c=float(input()),float(input()),float(input())" something like this:

```
param = input().split()
if len(param) == 1:
    print(cir(float(param[0])))
elif len(param) == 2:
    print(rec(float(param[0]), float(param[1])))
elif len(param) == 3:
    print(tri(float(param[0]), float(param[1]), float(param[2])))
```